# how do I write the dynamic button event handler code using c#

Tags: c#

```
int h = 100;n=4;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Button dybtn = new Button(); 
    dybtn.Location = new Point(80, h);
    dybtn.Height = 100; 
    dybtn.Width = 100;
    dybtn.Name = "dybtn";
    dybtn.Text = "";
    Controls.Add(dybtn);
    h = h + 100;
    dybtn.Click += new EventHandler(dybtn_Click);
}

private void dybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dynamic button is clicked");
}
```

I have created four dynamic buttons,when I write the event handling code all buttons are responding to the same code.

I need write the event handling code for each button individually using `c#`
So please let me know how write the event handling code for each button.

Comment: Ans what have you tried for doing this? You already have the code for adding the event handler just work out which button is which, via `h`? Then assign a different handler

Comment: Why do you want to write event handling code for each button individually?

Comment: @Sachin More than likely an attempt to write buttons next to each other that have different functionalities i.e. the OP is attempting to minimise the amount of code to write by being "clever"

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't think writing multiple event handlers would Minimize the amount of code in any way.

Comment: @Sachin no I mean writing the same design i.e. positions and names but the OP is changing the event handler. I think that's the objective

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The objective should not be separate Event Handlers, Separate event Handlers and Separate Event Handling Code should not be confused.

Comment: @Sachin that's not what I was trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike @TheLethalCoder answer, I would suggest you create just one handler for all the buttons and then use the `h` option to define different actions for each (Or whatever you have in mind)

```
void dybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    int h = btn.Location.Y;

    if (h == 100)
    {
        //Mission 1
    }
    else if (h == 200)
    {
        //Mission 2
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: This is basically what @Sachin has proposed

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes I suppose, but with a different way. more like yours

Comment: I know, but again if the event handler code for each button is quite large it will make the code harder to read, obviously a separate methods could be used but then you might as well just add separate event handlers

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you assign different names to the buttons that you are creating dynamically by doing something like **dybtn.Name = "dybtn" + i;**.

```
int h = 100;n=4;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Button dybtn = new Button(); 
    dybtn.Location = new Point(80, h);
    dybtn.Height = 100; 
    dybtn.Width = 100;
    dybtn.Name = "dybtn" + i;
    dybtn.Text = "";
    Controls.Add(dybtn);
    h = h + 100;
    dybtn.Click += new EventHandler(dybtn_Click);
}
```

Then in the event handler code, check for the name of button and execute code depending on that by using Switch..Case or If..Else.

Comment: If the code in the event handlers is quite large this will just make it harder to read, I would caution to assign the handler first then have separate ones per button

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on from my comment the only difference in each button is it's `y` location on the form. You track this by changing the value of the variable `h`. So if you do actually want to do this just alter it to do something like the following:

```
if (h == 100)
{
    dybtn.Click += new EventHandler(dybtn_Click1);
}
else if (h == 200)
{
    dybtn.Click += new EventHandler(dybtn_Click2);
}
//etc...
```

Or you can do the exact same thing with the `i` variable but this way you can control which event handler goes to which button based on the position.

However this does sound like bad code design and so if you just want a specific event based on different buttons just do them separately.